# Rspec feature test - verifying content in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a feature test that doesn't seem to be finding the content of the table that I expect. I should say that I'm new to feature tests so this is for sure something I am doing wrong. Basically I have a Groups table that takes in group name and response both of which should are displayed in the table but are not showing up when I run the test. Here is my error and code for clarity.

TEST

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Edit 'Bounce Back' Message" do
  scenario "Staff can change the response message" do
    visit "/groups"

    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"

    group = Group.create!(name: "Group A")
    person = Person.create!(groups: [group], phone_number: "+161655555555")

    expect(page).to have_content("You are now subscribed for updates")
    expect(page).to have_content("Group A")
  end
end
```

ERROR MESSAGE

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vHW5.png)

HERE IS THE PAGE

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDnT2.png)

As you can see it should display the response and group name on the page but it saying it doesn't show the words I expect? any help would be great!

VIEW

```
<div class="container text-center">
<div class="row">
<div class="text-center">
  <h3>Edit The "Bounce Back" Subscription Response</h3>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <% @group.each do |group| %>
      <tr>
        <td class='edit_response'><%= group.name.capitalize %></td>
        <td class='edit-response'><%= group.response %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_path(group) %></td>
      <tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you login the user first and only after that create subscription group, it won't be visible on the page unless you do a refresh. Maybe try creating the subscription group before logging in in the user?

```
scenario "Staff can change the response message" do
  visit "/groups"

  group = Group.create!(name: "Group A")
  person = Person.create!(groups: [group], phone_number: "+161655555555")

  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  fill_in "Email", with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"

  expect(page).to have_content("You are now subscribed for updates")
  expect(page).to have_content("Group A")
end
```